# iOS Facebook friends list - image url, user id, name

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

In iOS facebooks SDK, i would like to get the facebook user id, friend name, and image URL (user profile pic).

**Question:**

1. I have used FBFriendPickerViewController, it displays friend name, but is there a way I can get the image URL and facebook id.
2. Also is FBFriendPickerViewController the correct approach to actually list the friends list. Or is there a different API I should be using.

Comment: Are you using graphApi?

Comment: How do I check if the graph API is being used. Pardon my ignorance.

Comment: i will post the one answer plz check ... i think its help for u  :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
FBRequest* friendsRequest = [FBRequest requestForMyFriends];

[friendsRequest startWithCompletionHandler: ^(FBRequestConnection *connection,NSDictionary* result,NSError *error)
 {
     NSArray* friends = [result objectForKey:@"data"];

     for (NSDictionary<FBGraphUser>* friend in friends)
     {
         NSLog(@"friend id = %@", friend.id);
         NSLog(@"friend name = %@", friend.username);
         NSLog(@"friend pic url = %@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture?", friend.id]);

     }
 }];
```

Refer - [How to get the list of friend without opening FBFriendPickerViewController iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15709226/how-to-get-the-list-of-friend-without-opening-fbfriendpickerviewcontroller-ios)

Answer (score 1):

**[First U down load the classes from this link and this link help for u](https://github.com/reallylongaddress/iPhone-Facebook-Graph-API)**

```
//Need to declare
**@property (nonatomic, retain)**

 FbGraph *fbGraph;
 UserProfile *profil_obj;
 MBProgressHUD *HUD;


 -(IBAction)FacebookButtonPressed
{

   if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"isLogin"]==NO)
    {
    }
   else
      {

    HUD=[MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
    [HUD setLabelText:@"Loading Profile..."];

       }
   NSString *client_id = @"********";
   self.fbGraph = [[FbGraph alloc] initWithFbClientID:client_id];
  [fbGraph authenticateUserWithCallbackObject:self andSelector:@selector(fbGraphCallback:) 
                     andExtendedPermissions:@"user_photos,user_videos,publish_stream,offline_access,user_checkins,friends_checkins,user_birthday"];

}
```

**STEP_2**

```
 -(void)post_wall{


   FbGraphResponse *fb_graph_response = [fbGraph doGraphGet:@"me/feed" withGetVars:nil];
    SBJSON *parser = [[SBJSON alloc] init];
    NSMutableDictionary *parsed_json = [parser objectWithString:fb_graph_response.htmlResponse error:nil];

     NSString *get_string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/picture", [parsed_json objectForKey:@"id"]];
    FbGraphResponse *fb_graph_response1 = [fbGraph doGraphGet:get_string withGetVars:nil];
NSLog(@"getMeimagePressed:  %@", fb_graph_response1.imageResponse);
    [parsed_json setObject:fb_graph_response1.imageResponse forKey:@"profileImage"];



  if([parsed_json count]>0)
     {
    profil_obj.userprofile_dic=parsed_json;



    if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"isLogin"]==NO)
    {
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"isLogin"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    }


}
else {
    [parser release];
    UIAlertView *ErrorAlrt = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Message" message:@"Please check your internet connection and try again.." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [ErrorAlrt show];
    [ErrorAlrt release];


}

}
```

**STEP-3**

```
 - (void)fbGraphCallback:(id)sender {

if ( (fbGraph.accessToken == nil) || ([fbGraph.accessToken length] == 0) ) {


    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] 
                              initWithTitle:@"FailMessage" 
                              message:@"You are Not Login to Facebook." 
                              delegate:self 
                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
                              otherButtonTitles:nil, 
                              nil];
    [alertView show];
    [alertView release];
    NSHTTPCookieStorage* cookies = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
    for (NSHTTPCookie* cookie in [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] cookies]) {
        [cookies deleteCookie:cookie];
    }


} else {

    if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"isLogin"]==NO)
    {


        profil_obj=[[UserProfile alloc] initWithNibName:@"UserProfile" bundle:nil];
        [self performSelector:@selector(post_wall)];
        [HUD hide:YES]; 
        [self presentModalViewController:profil_obj animated:YES];
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] 
                                  initWithTitle:@"SucessMessage" 
                                  message:@"You are Sucessfully Login to Facebook." 
                                  delegate:self 
                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
                                  otherButtonTitles:nil, 
                                  nil];
        [alertView show];
        [alertView release];


    }
    else
    {


        profil_obj=[[UserProfile alloc] initWithNibName:@"UserProfile" bundle:nil];
        [self performSelector:@selector(post_wall)];
        [self presentModalViewController:profil_obj animated:YES];
        [HUD hide:YES]; 

    }




        }

 }
```