# Facebook SDK friendlist request

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

I got a time request timed out error when I try to load all of my facebook friend.

I have FBSessionOpen state.
My code:

```
[FBRequestConnection startForMyFriendsWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id data, NSError *error) {
    if(error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
        [self.delegate didFinishLoadingFriendsWithResult:[ErrorResponse errorResponseWithMessage:@"Failed to load user friends from Facebook"] succes:NO];
        return;
    }
    NSArray* friends = (NSArray*)[data data];
    NSLog(@"You have %d friends", [friends count]);
    NSLog(@"Friends: %@", friends);
    [self.delegate didFinishLoadingFriendsWithResult:friends succes:YES];
}];
```

Error message:

```
Error: Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk Code=5 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 5.)" UserInfo=0x1d1e3a30 {com.facebook.sdk:ErrorInnerErrorKey=Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out." UserInfo=0x1d1e16a0 {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?sdk=ios&fields=id%2Cname%2Cusername%2Cfirst_name%2Clast_name&migration_bundle=fbsdk%3A20130120&format=json&access_token=CAAHyDtIdIi0BAM6ZCtXb3Yb5jzuPQ7Tvc6mYg1zO1ZBjoEqZBI5sB5eFYQiTp6s0euVhMTQcl1yqXnaLT118BIBaaEtY1hLEpKq1ptG6y4dHR8BknAOTZCpRUvYlJlT6KbL42MXk2VaMZBvGRwIvs1644FSxy5vVRBSTIFsNZAzIyRpQjjhIA1, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?sdk=ios&fields=id%2Cname%2Cusername%2Cfirst_name%2Clast_name&migration_bundle=fbsdk%3A20130120&format=json&access_token=CAAHyDtIdIi0BAM6ZCtXb3Yb5jzuPQ7Tvc6mYg1zO1ZBjoEqZBI5sB5eFYQiTp6s0euVhMTQcl1yqXnaLT118BIBaaEtY1hLEpKq1ptG6y4dHR8BknAOTZCpRUvYlJlT6KbL42MXk2VaMZBvGRwIvs1644FSxy5vVRBSTIFsNZAzIyRpQjjhIA1, NSLocalizedDescription=The request timed out., NSUnderlyingError=0x1d1e3800 "The request timed out."}, com.facebook.sdk:HTTPStatusCode=200, com.facebook.sdk:ErrorSessionKey=<FBSession: 0x1d1b0c90, state: FBSessionStateOpen, loginHandler: 0x1d1b0db0, appID: 547620445299245, urlSchemeSuffix: , tokenCachingStrategy:<FBSessionTokenCachingStrategy: 0x1d1afdd0>, expirationDate: 2013-09-28 09:49:39 +0000, refreshDate: 2013-07-30 14:08:31 +0000, attemptedRefreshDate: 0001-12-30 00:00:00 +0000, permissions:(
    "read_friendlists"
)>}
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: which facebook SDK is used in this? ios sdk 3.1 or other?

Comment: 3.2.1 maybe I should update, good idea

Comment: 3.6 version behaves the same

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you just did not ask for needed permission from Facebook. Just use

```
[FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"read_friendlists", @"user_status", @"friends_status", nil] allowLoginUI:allowLoginUI completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState status, NSError *error) {

    [self sessionStateChanged:session state:status error:error];


}];
```

And then

```
 FBRequest* friendsRequest = [FBRequest requestForMyFriends];
friendsRequest.session = FBSession.activeSession;

[friendsRequest startWithCompletionHandler: ^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
        NSDictionary* result,
        NSError *error) {
    NSArray* friends = [result objectForKey:@"data"];
    NSLog(@"Found: %i friends", friends.count);
    NSLog(@"friends: %@", result);
    for (NSDictionary<FBGraphUser>* friend in friends) {
        NSLog(@"I have a friend named %@ with id %@", friend.name, friend.id);
    }
}];
```

Comment: it should be work but I got an empty list: "friends: {
    data =     (
    );
}"

Comment: Check your app settings in Facebook, check app permissions.

Comment: If I get null result means ?

Comment: it's giving  { data = ( ); } or sometimes summury = { count = 8; }

Answer (score 0):

see my answer in StackOverflow for getting facebook friend list with custom design

[How to get the list of friend without opening FBFriendPickerViewController iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15709226/how-to-get-the-list-of-friend-without-opening-fbfriendpickerviewcontroller-ios/15717293#15717293)

Comment: thanks, if will not working, I will change to your implementation:D.

Comment: your solution return an empty dictionary: "Printing description of result:
{
    data =     (
    );
}" without error